# Is there an online list of Kindertransport records?

Tags: 20th-century, germany, immigration, united-kingdom

*Kindertransport* was an operation to save Jewish children from Germany and occupied countries in 1938 and 1939. Almost 10,000 children were transported to the UK through this program.

While I have found a [web site dedicated to this operation](http://kindertransport.org/default.aspx), it does not seem to have any information on specific children rescued.

Does such a list exist, and, if so, can it be searched online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be some information available at The National Archives described [here](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/SearchUI/Details?uri=C9260) which leads you to a searchable catalogue at http://www.movinghere.org.uk/default.htm.

UK passenger lists do not generally record travel within Europe: see [TNA](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/records/looking-for-person/passengers.htm)

Have you seen [wjr.org.uk/about-us/kindertransport](http://wjr.org.uk/about-us/kindertransport) and [ajr.org.uk](http://ajr.org.uk)?
Also, [kindertransport.org/resources.aspx?cat=9](http://kindertransport.org/resources.aspx?cat=9) (which you've probably looked at) might be a good starting point.

There is a GREAT resource for family members available here...just need to send request for your family member who was on the KT...  https://www.worldjewishrelief.org/about-us/your-family-history

Answer (score 6):

Yesterday, online records related to the Kindertransport children became available through [FindMyPast](http://search.findmypast.co.uk/search-world-Records/kindertransport):

> This is a fascinating collection of digitised government documents
>   relating to the Kindertransport operation, dating from 1939 to 1945,
>   held by The National Archives. The records may reveal when and where
>   your ancestor arrived in Britain. This is not a complete list of all
>   the children rescued from Nazi occupied Europe, but the records give a
>   unique insight into the experience of the Kinder from their arrival,
>   between 1938 and 1939, to the end of WWII.

This collection appears to be co-extensive with those held by the National Archives but this may provide another way for you to access them.

Answer (score 5):

Try posting a query to the e-mail listserves at JewishGen.org -- they are a knowledgeable bunch and the site is free to use.