# How to find records of a refugee from the Nazis?

Tags: 20th-century, germany, poland

I am trying to find my husband's great gradnmother's details. She was born on July 15, 1913 in Germany or Poland. Her name was Mae Bernstein. Her parents were Max and Edith Bernstein (from her marriage certificate). We have been told she was on the kindertransport. On her marriage certificate, her name is recorded as Mae Bernstein Benson Branson. Trying to find out what happened as she never ever told anyone what happened. She said she had siblings but gave no names.

Trying to find any records.

Comment: I presume she was Jewish? Also, http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2844/56 might be of use to you.

Comment: If the birth year was 1913, she was not a child during the Kindertransport (1938-1939).

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of websites on Kindertransport that you should try. They have information and links that will give you ideas of where to search.

The sites include:

- [The Kindertransport Association](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=http://www.kindertransport.org/&ei=_UZKUr6BPaGM2gWlloGYAg&usg=AFQjCNHsflU6P-pLHl6RnPQT8S4UuBEKBw&sig2=e2iNZGhu17n9isWwAS7Y6g&bvm=bv.53371865,d.b2I)
- [The Kindertransport special interest group of the Association of Jewish Refugees](http://www.ajr.org.uk/kindertransport)
- [The Wikipedia article on Kindertransport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindertransport)

You should also [search the Central Database of Shoah Victims' Names](http://db.yadvashem.org/names/search.html?language=en) for her parents. Try variations in spelling and the advanced search.

However, @bgwiehle makes a good point in his comment that if she was born in 1913, she was likely too old to be part of Kindertransport, since generally children up to 17 years old were accepted, and it took place from 1938 to 1940. So you should question your sources of your information.

Answer (score 0):

The [UK Moving Here](http://www.movinghere.org.uk/default.htm.) site as mentioned in this answer: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2845/104 may be helpful.